# Using Lambda expressions and the In Restrictor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Using Lambda expressions and the In Restrictor

I have a query where I want to restrict the results based on a value of one field, and if it is contained in a list of values.

```
   public List<Client> GetClientsByExtractIds(List<Guid> extractIds)
    {
        AJGDMSStagingContext context = new AJGDMSStagingContext(STAGING_CONNECTION_STRING);

        return context.Clients.ToList();
    }
```

So it needs to be something like : `Clients.ExtractId.Contains(ExtractIds)`

One option I have is obtaining all clients and then just cycling through all of them in memory, but I’d prefer to get it directly from the DB.

Comment: What is your data coming from?

Comment: In Restrictor.... In(extractId1, extractId2, extractId3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return context.Clients.Where(c => extractIds.Contains(c.ExtractId)).ToList();
```

Comment: To add to that: for performance purposes, I would declare `extractIds` as a `HashSet`. But that's micro-optimization anyway.

Comment: Bingo. I didn't realize that like all things linq, it just appears a little backwards. I ran the profiler and could see where it had "[t0].[ExtractId] IN (@p0)'"